# Counting the number of vowels in a string in C

Tags: arrays, c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zst9c.png)

I'm solving the decryption problem in C language

There's a problem.

There's a process of counting the vowels in the string,

code not reading the number of vowels properly in that 'countingmeasure'

I was so curious that I debugged it,

count ++ doesn't work at'o'.

I'm really curious why this is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    char original[15] = { 't','f','l','e','k','v','i','d','v','r','j','l','i','v',NULL };


    printf("암호화된 문자열 : %s\n", original);
    printf("원본 가능 문자열  \n");
    printf("\n");



    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)//모음이 7개일때만 출력을 어떻게 시킬까?
    {
        char change[14] = { 0 };
        int counter=0;
        char a;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {   
            a = original[i] + j;

            if (a > 122)
            {
                original[i] -= 26 ;
            }

            if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
            {
                counter++;
            }           


            
            printf("%c", original[i] + j);
        }
        printf(" %d\n",counter);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "`count ++` doesn't work" mean?

Comment: What exactly makes you think that `"count ++ doesn't work at 'o'"`? When you run the program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, does the debugger say that the value of `counter` before executing the line `counter++` is the same as the value after executing this line?

Comment: your addition doesn't wrap around, so your chars go outsode the range a-z

Comment: What is `122`?  I suppose that is probably `'z'`, and you should write `'z'` for 2 reasons: 1) it is a lot more clear to the reader what `'z'` is, and 2) there are actually some encodings in which `'z' != 122`. They are rare these days, but they do exist.

Comment: "*I was so curious that I debugged it*" I like the attitude

Answer (score 1):

`a = original[i] + j;` doesn't make any sense, since `a` is a `char` and the result might not fit inside it. Specifically, "character value + 26" might be larger than 127. [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Furthermore, arithmetic on any symbols except `'0'` to `'9'` isn't well-defined and they are not guaranteed to be allocated adjacently. Also please refrain from using  hard-coded "magic numbers" in source code. Instead of 122 you should use `'z'` etc.

There are several ways you can fix the program.

- The quick & dirty solution is to do `unsigned char a` on the existing program, if you are content with "it just works, but I don't even know what I'm doing".
- A better solution is to declare a string of vowels and then for every character in the input string, do a `strchr()` search in the vowel string for a match. (Correct but naive and slow, good enough beginner solution.)
- A professional solution would be to create a look-up table of 128 booleans like
  `const bool LOOKUP [128] = { ['A'] = true, ['a'] = true, ['E'] = true, ... };` Then check `if(item[i] == LOOKUP[ item[i] ]) /* then vowel */`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use functions.
2. NULL is a pointer not zero or null terminating character
3. Use string literals.
4. use standard functions to change the case (tolower, toupper)

```
char *mystrchr(const char *str, const char lt, int ignoreCase)
{
    while(*str) 
    {
        if(ignoreCase) 
            if(tolower((unsigned char)*str) == tolower((unsigned char)lt)) return (char *)str;
        else 
            if(*str == lt) return (char *)str;
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

size_t count(const char *haystack, const char *needle, int ignoreCase)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while(*haystack)
    {
        if(mystrchr(needle, *haystack, ignoreCase)) count++;
        haystack++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "tflekvidvrjliv";

    printf("%zu\n", count(str, "aeiou", 1));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with this. If we are to provide the full solution, there are far more efficient (and less sloppily formatted) solutions...

Comment: @Lundin I have no idea what you mean